# Count how many equal values in 2 columns (ignore duplicates and empty cells) in excel

Tags: excel

I tried to search the web but no good answer came up.
I got 2 columns (not with same number of rows), that contains values.
I need to count how many times the values are equal ignoring empty cells and duplicates.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the two columns you have are A and B (with data beginning in row 2 because there are headers in row 1). You could make a third column in C with the following formula:

```
=A2=B2
```

This will return TRUE for rows where the values in column A and column B are equal to each other and FALSE for those where they are not.